# Why Haven't the Parsing Helpers Been Made Easier to Use?

Tags: c#, parsing, language-design, nullable, deprecated

Given that the .NET team has stated (I'll find a source...) that they regret the design of the primitive type's parsing methods (e.g. [`Int32.TryParse(String s, out Int32 result)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)) why haven't these been updated with a more obvious and client-friendly variant?

**Framework Version:**

```
Int32? numValue;
Int32 placeHolder;
if (! Int32.TryParse("not a number", out placeHolder))
    numValue = 10;
```

**Improved Version:**

```
var numValue = Int32.Parse("not a number", 10);
```

Where the signature for the improved parsing method is:

```
public static Int32? Parse(String s, Int32? defaultValue = null);
```

And it might have a naive implementation of:

```
public static Int32? Parse(String s, Int32? defaultValue = null) {
    Int32 temp;
    return ! Int32.TryParse(s, out temp)
        ? defaultValue
        : temp;
}
```

Comment: With the creation of [`TypeConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) I don't really see a need to replace the `Parse` methods.

Comment: @Romoku `TypeConverter` is powerful, but (a) doesn't seem as easy to use as the proposed improvement and (b) seems heavy-handed in implementation. It handles an infinite number of cases where the `Parse` methods really only need to work with primitives; what's the performance going to be like?

Comment: Are you asking why the BCL isn't this way? Well, off the top of my head, using nullables will box your value type so you get a performance impact from that if it's done everywhere. Secondly, if you _know_ your input is _supposed_ to be good, then why have the overhead of boxing/null check when an exception could be thrown instead? (it would be an _exceptional case_)? EDIT: Besides, you could always roll your own extension method on `String`.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair The question is really one of "where is my syntactic sugar for writing cruddy `TryParse` code with `out` parameters when my input comes from an dubious source and will *likely* be bad?" `TryParse` is awkward and `Nullable<T>` with default parameters could make for a much, much nicer implementation.

Comment: Another thing, most likely at this point the methods are "too big to fail" -- probably a _huge_ breaking change if it were to be applied. I honestly have no problem with usage of the existing parsing methods... but probably because I almost _never_ have to use nullable versions of value types (seems like an _anti_ design to me except for some special cases like database I/O) EDIT: Also, this question might be better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com; it seems pretty open-ended for discussion, speculative, and subjective.

Comment: @Yuck I just reread the question, sorry if I misunderstood. Your question is directly related to the `TryParse` method? The existing `Parse` that throws exceptions is fine as-is or are you suggesting to replace _both_ methods with your new implementation (or equivalent thereof)?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair As you've suggested, I have already written extension methods on `String` to support one-line, exception handling parsing with support for default values. I just feel that the .NET BCL should have something similar baked in by now since it's so common -- at least in business applications.

Comment: @Yuck I answered, and added another consideration (#6). Personally, I don't find such usage that common. I don't build many small business applications frequently (just a couple large ones), and in my experience nullable value type handling is generally just for the I/O layers; all my API/business/layers stick to valid non-nullable value types -- `null` usually has no meaning for an `int` usually; I typically see it as a code smell outside of I/O layers that require it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there would be a definitive answer to this unless someone from the BCL team has a story to tell.

Some considerations might be:

1. Changing the methods would constitute a *large* breaking change to
   existing code bases with very little (debatable if any) gain. Some
   might argue that it would be a detriment for the reasons below.
2. Nullable types <s>box the wrapped</s> wrap the underlying value causing a (minor) performance hit
   always even when you expect your parse to succeed and don't want a
   nullable type anyway.
3. If you *know* your input is *supposed* to be valid, then the `Parse`
   method throws exceptions for the *exceptional case* that the input
   is invalid. This is generally more performant as we don't have extra
   error handling code for when we don't need it, and expected from a
   design point of view. If you plan on handling the invalid case,
   that's what `TryParse` is for.
4. Confusion between `int Parse(string, int? defaultValue)` and `int
   Parse(string)`, mostly with regards to their error handling. Notice
   I've remove the optional part of the first method otherwise it would
   make no sense to have both methods (you would never be able to call
   your method without explicitly passing in `null`). At this point, it
   would be a bit confusing as one overload throws an exception on
   failure whereas the other one does not. There are a few exceptions
   to this, such as
   [Type.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5cf8k43.aspx)
   but they're generally rare and in such cases they make use of an *explicitly named parameter* indicating that it *will* or *will not* throw an exception.
5. Another benefit of `TryParse` as designed is that it is pretty
   explicit by way of its API for handling the pass/fail result. Rather
   than a magic number/result (`null`) indicating a failure, it returns
   a *separate* true/false value. Now, *some* mechanisms do this
   (`String.IndexOf` for example returning -1) so it's debatable if
   this is a good thing or a bad thing. Depending on your practice,
   using the return `true/false` value might be easier, or using the
   magic `null` result might be. But they decided I guess to not muddy
   the waters with two methods doing the exact same thing but with
   slightly different signatures/return values.
6. Another consideration is how common *nullable* value types are. Are
   you really using `Int32?` in many places? Or is it just for
   error/input handling? In my experience, nullable values are *mostly*
   used for database I/O (and even then, not that often). The only
   other times could be for input from non-trusted sources which would
   only be for the initial interfacing; all underlying code would still
   be typed against the non-nullable `Int32`. In such case you have two
   methods, the original:

   ```
   int input;
   if (TryParse(someString, out input))
       DoSomethingValid(input); //valid! Do something
   else
       ErrorMessage()//not valid, error!
   ```

   Or your suggestion:

   ```
   int? input = Parse(someString)
   if (input != null)
       DoSomethingValid(input.GetValueOrDefault())//valid! Do something
   else
       ErrorMessage()//not valid, error!
   ```

   Note how *similar* both are. Your suggestion really provides very
   little, if anything to this case. Also note the usage of
   `GetValueOrDefault()`, this is *actually* the [faster/better way to access the wrapped value](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/20/nullable-micro-optimizations-part-one/) if you know it's non-null, but rarely (at
   least from what I see on the internet) is it used over the `Value`
   accessor. If the BCL added/changed the `Parse` method as you
   suggest, I think *a lot* of people would be unnecessarily hitting
   the `Value` accessor.

   I can't comment *specifically* on cases using nullable values
   significantly throughout an application design and/or its layers,
   but in my experience they are rarely used or should be rarely used (to me, it's a code smell almost on the level of "stringly-typed" data)

Ultimately, I believe *part* of the reason why extension methods were added (aside from Linq) was to allow users to roll their own API as needed. In your case, you can *easily* add an extension method to obtain the syntax you want:

```
public static Int32? Parse(this String s, Int32? defaultValue = null)
{
    Int32 temp;
    return !Int32.TryParse(s, out temp)
        ? defaultValue
        : temp;
}

string validString = "1";
int? parsed = validString.Parse(); //1
int? failParsed = "asdf".Parse(9); //9
```

The teams generally favour maintaining the status quo and additions have to provide a significant enough *benefit* to be added to the system, and the team also considers what workarounds already exist in the API as-is. I'd suggest that given the extension method option, it's not that big of a concern to change the API considering the signficant breaking nature of it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put a lot of thought into this.  These are very good reasons and I can accept your position that extension methods largely solve for these "gaps".

Comment: @Yuck No problem! It was actually a lot of fun to think about it and put my thoughts down in writing, even if I don't have a definitive answer to give. :)

Comment: The use of nullable types doesn't necessary imply boxing. `Nullable<T>` is a value type, not a reference type... Boxing only occurs in certain cases (e.g. if you assign it to a `object` variable), but if you're just using a local nullable variable, there is no boxing involved.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: Of course, don't know where my head was at. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

This signature:

```
public static Int32? Parse(String s, Int32? defaultValue = null);
```

would conflict with the existing `Parse(string s)` overload, because there is no way to tell them apart if the optional argument is not specified. The existing methods will probably never be changed or removed, because it would break compatibility with existing code.

However it would be possible to create overloads of `TryParse` that don't take a `out int value` parameter:

```
public static int? TryParse(string s)
```

Note that you don't need to add a parameter for the default value: you can use the null coalescing operator instead.

```
string s = ...
int value = int.TryParse(s) ?? 0;
```

Comment: Good point that the overloaded signature would conflict, but it could be called something else instead. `SafeParse` maybe as it would never throw an exception?

Comment: @Yuck, personnally I prefer `TryParse`, because I think that's how the existing `TryParse` method should have been designed. The "Try" prefix also implies that it won't throw.